# C# BitConverter.ToSingle equivalent in Python

Tags: c#, python, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I have some code in C# that converts bytes to float using BitConverter.ToSingle function, like this:

```
float tmp_float = BitConverter.ToSingle(jobBff, cnt);
```

As I found out from this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

four bytes go in (just not sure in what order), use 1 bit for sign, 8 bits for exponent, and the rest of the bits for the fraction.

In C# I just inform a buffer, the starting position, and C# does the rest of the job. Is there an equivalent function for that on Python? Or how can I convert those 4 bytes to a float?

Thanks!

---

Solution: as suggested by Kyle in the answer, I ended up using the code below, which worked for me.

```
def prepare_bytes_on_string(array):
    output = ''
    for i in range(0, len(array), 1):
        #Just as a reminder:
        #hex(x)                    #value: '0xffffbfde1605'
        #hex(x)[2:]                #value: 'ffffbfde1605'
        #hex(x)[2:].decode('hex')  #value: '\xff\xff\xbf\xde\x16\x05'
        output += hex(array[i])[2:].decode('hex')
    return output

bytes_array = [0x38, 0xcd, 0x87, 0xc0]
val = prepare_bytes_on_string(bytes_array)
output = unpack('f', val)
print output
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that this issue might invoke endian trouble. You might be better off using Skeet's `EndianBitConverter` in [miscutils](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/struct.html).  You would want the `struct.unpack( 'f', buffer )` method (possibly with some endianess adjustment, see the documentation for that).

Comment: Is this also available in python 2.7?

Comment: It's been available for quite a while, actually.  Here's [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Comment: Edited the question to include the used solution.